# £ = $ with OT4 and tgpagella loaded

Tags: fonts

There seems to be a incompatibility between the OT4 font encoding and the tgpagella package. When I load either of the packages, the pound sign comes out as $ (a dangarous thing since we are in a financial crisis already =;-). I have these two packages pre-loaded by a journal file. Can I do anything about this?

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{tgpagella}
%\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}


15€ + \$17 = 13£?


\end{document}
```

Comment: why can't you use `\usepackage[OT4,T1]{fontenc} `?

Comment: OK. This helps. Thanks! I will suggest this to the journal, because it is their style that has to be changed.

Comment: @StefanMüller OT4 is really an outdated encoding; Polish has full support in the T1 encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OT* font encodings have the problem that the they have 128 slot positions only.
There is no place in the OT4 encoding for the sterling. The symbol is supported by a crude hack. The symbols sterling and dollar share the same slot. The italics shape `it` and a special shape for the upright form `ui` contains the sterling and the other shapes the dollar:

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\textdollar}{OT4}{\hmode@bgroup
   \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
      \slshape
   \else
      \upshape
   \fi
   \char`\$\egroup}

\DeclareTextCommand{\textsterling}{OT4}{\hmode@bgroup
   \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
      \itshape
   \else
      \fontshape{ui}\selectfont
   \fi
   \char`\$\egroup}
```

However, TeX Gyre Pagella does not support this and always uses the dollar sign. The font shape `ui` is not even defined:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT4/qpl/m/ui' undefined
(Font)              using `OT4/qpl/m/n' instead on input line 12.
```

As solution `\textsterling` can be redefined for the OT4 encoding to use a different encoding without such trouble:

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\textsterling}{OT4}{% 
  \begingroup\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\textsterling}\endgroup
}
```

A better solution is to use a better encoding like `T1` as suggested by Herbert.
This can also be done after the class is loaded:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Package `fontenc` is the exception in the package management system of LaTeX. It can be loaded several times with different options.

For the case that some text is still using `OT4`, I would add the redefinition of `\textsterling` for OT4 and use a better encoding like `T1`.